# Is there an option to hide clang inline warnings in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, clang, qt-creator

**Question**

Can QtCreator be configured hide warnings in the editor window while still showing the warning icon on the left side?

**Description**

QtCreator 4.5 with Clang Code Model enabled shows warnings in 2 locations:

- inlined in the code editor
- in a pop-up appearing when hovering over an icon on the left side

In my opinion the former clutters GUI and the latter is both sufficient and less intrusive.

Here's an example:
[image: Inline warning in QtCreator]

I looked at QtCreator options including Code Model options and could not find any setting for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Options > Text Editor > Display > Annotation next to line.

It helps me in Qt Creator 4.4.1.

Answer (score 12):

For Qt Creator 4.7.0, you have to go:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Display

And then uncheck the 'Line annotations' option